# Create a flowchart in R

Tags: r, shiny, diagrammer

I have these two variables and want create a graph similar to this or any fancier version :

```
variable_x <- c("bird", "animal","season")
selection_x<- c("crow","tiger","winter")
```

result: 
[image: Output]

Comment: Mmm, An interesting need. I don't know if there's a package for this specifically but you could use ggplot for it. You would have to calculate x and y positions for everything. geom_text could be used to concatenate and print the text you want and stat_ellipse to create the circles.

Comment: There’s a package called: DiagrammeR

Comment: If you've already got a package in mind to use and it's reasonably well documented, it's easier to help if you get started on solving the problem and post what you're trying to debug, rather than us trying to write the code from scratch for you